# How to read Gzipped file on Azure without (.gz) extension in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file which is Gzipped with no .gz extension on Azure. 
Path: https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xx/xx/0_2017/xxx/0/100103900

I would like to read the gzipped file in spark/scala. I have gone through a few posts which suggested me to use sc.binaryFiles() but getting unresolved errors.

Tried but no luck

```
spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").textFile(newFollowersStartDatePath).show()
```

[Sample output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3phdL.png)

I believe spark reads gzipped file by automatically decompressing it which has terminated with .gz. looking for some help to read a gzipped file with no extension specified.

Expected Output would be a list of ids (one column)

```
1343423
2342342
2343232
2342343
```

Comment: Can you please post your output as text in your post?

Comment: added the expected output. please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `binaryFiles` done the trick

```
sparkSession.sparkContext.binaryFiles(filePath)
      .flatMap({ case (_, portableDataStream) =>
        val dataInputStream = new java.io.DataInputStream(
          new GZIPInputStream(portableDataStream.open))
        Iterator.continually( Try(dataInputStream.readLong())).takeWhile(result => {
          result match {
            case Success(_) => true
            case Failure(_) =>  dataInputStream.close()
              false
          }
        })
      }).flatMap(_.toOption).toDS
  }
```